# What is a semaphore value on process exit?

Tags: linux, semaphore

If a named semaphore's value is increased by post operation from a process would it retain this value even if the process exits abruptly? Will the restarted/re-executed process be able to observe this increased value?

Answer (score 2):

Named semaphores are stored in persistent storage unless you don't call `sem_unlink`. According to the man page:

> ```
>    On Linux, named semaphores are created in a virtual filesystem,
>    normally mounted under /dev/shm, with names of the form
>    sem.somename.
> ```

and according to the man page again, this should answer your question (simply yes.):

> The sem_open(3) function creates a new named semaphore or
> opens an existing named semaphore.  After the semaphore
> has been opened, it can be operated on using sem_post(3)
> and sem_wait(3).  When a process has finished using the
> semaphore, it can use sem_close(3) to close the semaphore.
> When all processes have finished using the semaphore, it
> can be removed from the system using sem_unlink(3).